# Add information to FormData when sending via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX to save some data. I need to save FormData and other info. I am using the below function, but I am not sure how to add the other information to the FormData object. Could you please help?

```js
function vignetteAjax(company_id, client_id, type_id, url) {
  var formData = document.getElementById("edit_form");
  var fd = new FormData(myform);

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "post",
    data: {
      "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
      "company_id": company_id,
      "client_id": client_id,
      "type_id": type_id,
    },
    beforeSend: function() {},
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('done');
      $("#policies_list").empty().html(data);
    },
    complete: function() {
      console.log('compete');
    }
  });

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not simply add a `fd` key to your `data` ?

Comment: @JeremyThille — Because jQuery can't serialize a FormData object to the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `append` method to add the additional data to the `FormData` object, then send just the `FormData` object.

```
var formData = document.getElementById("edit_form");
var fd = new FormData(myform);
fd.append("_token", "{{ csrf_token() }}");
fd.append("company_id", company_id);
fd.append("client_id", client_id);
fd.append("type_id", type_id);

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "post",
    data: fd,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you just need to append the other data with your `FormData`

```
var fd = new FormData(myform );
fd.append('NameHere',"ValueHere");
// Rest of Code
```

Answer (score -1):

You can send the entire Form-Data via Post

```
data: {
    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
    "company_id": company_id,
    "client_id": client_id,
    "type_id": type_id,
    formData: $('#edit_form').serialize()},
},
```

Also, hence you are using jQuery, you dont need to use document.getElementById("edit_form"). You can directly use $('#edit_form').
On the PHP Side (assuming you use PHP), use parse_str to unserialize.

```
parse_str($_POST['formData'], $formData);
```

Comment: `serialize` cannot handle file inputs, which is the primary reason for using `FormData` with jQuery ajax